# Prove that for any $x \ge 0, y\ge 0$ the inequality $\frac12(x+y)^2+\frac14(x+y) \ge x \sqrt y + y\sqrt x$ holds

Tags: inequality, arithmetic, means

Prove that for any $x \ge 0$, $y\ge 0$, the inequality $$\frac12(x+y)^2+\frac14(x+y) \ge x \sqrt y + y\sqrt x$$ is true.

Okay, so I thought of the inequality of the means.
Not just about the arithmetic and the geometric, but about the harmonic and the quadratic mean.
But where can I use them and how, I don't really know. I also thought of showing that

$$\frac12(x+y)^2 + \frac14(x+y) - (x \sqrt y + y \sqrt x) > 0$$

Maybe by assumption and contradicting the assumption.
All the ideas are welcome! Thank you!!

Comment: I have posted an answer. The idea is to use the AM-GM inequality repeatedly. Hope it helps.

Comment: Duplicate target found instantly [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cfrac12(x%2By)%5E2%2B%5Cfrac14(x%2By)%20%5Cge%20x%20%5Csqrt%20y%20%2B%20y%5Csqrt%20x%24)

Comment: @MartinR I personally *would* have preferred to close the other question as a duplicate of this one, as there is more content here.

Comment: @lonestudent: More content in what sense? Because this question has three answers and the older question only one? The answer to the older question looks fine to me, and the quality of the questions is comparable IMO. – It would have been better to look for a duplicate *before* posting answers, and post additional answers to the duplicate target, if necessary.

Comment: @MartinR Yes. I just wanted to share my opinion.  Because I've seen examples of this before.  The old question was closed as a dupe of the new one, because the new one was a dupe, but got more contextual answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have an idea! We want to show
$$2(x+y)^2 + (x+y) \ge 4(x\sqrt y + y\sqrt x)$$
i.e.,
$$2x^2 + 2y^2 + 4xy + x + y \ge 4(x\sqrt y + y\sqrt x)$$
First of all, using the AM-GM inequality,
$$2x^2 + 2y^2 \ge 2\cdot \sqrt{4x^2y^2} = 4xy$$
so that $$2x^2 + 2y^2 + y \ge 4xy + y \tag{1}$$
Using the AM-GM inequality again, $$4xy + y \ge 2\sqrt{4xy^2} = 4y\sqrt x \tag{2}$$
Also,
$$4xy + x \ge 4x\sqrt y \tag{3}$$
From $(1)$ and $(2)$, we have $$2x^2 + 2y^2 + y \ge 4y\sqrt{x} \tag{4}$$
The desired inequality follows by adding $(3)$ and $(4)$.

Answer (score 0):

It sufficies to prove that :

$$
\begin{align}2xy+\frac 14(x+y)&≥\sqrt {xy}(\sqrt x+\sqrt y)\end{align}
$$

by AM-GM inequality.

Then, it sufficies to prove that :

$$
\begin{align}2xy+\frac 18\left(\sqrt x+\sqrt y\right)^2&≥\sqrt {xy}\left(\sqrt x+\sqrt y\right)\end{align}
$$

by Cauchy-Schwars inequality.

which is correct, since

$$
\begin{align}16xy+\left(\sqrt x+\sqrt y\right)^2-8\sqrt {xy}\left(\sqrt x+\sqrt y\right)=\\
\left(4\sqrt {xy}-\left(\sqrt x+\sqrt y\right)\right)^2≥0 \thinspace.\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

We have that

$$\frac12(x+y)^2+\frac14(x+y) \ge x \sqrt y + y\sqrt x\iff \frac14(x+y)\left[2(x+y)+1)\right] \ge x \sqrt y + y\sqrt x$$

which is trivially true for $xy=0$, then assuming $xy\neq 0$ and dividing by $\sqrt{xy}$ it is equivalent to
$$\frac14\left(\sqrt{\frac xy}+\sqrt{\frac yx}\right)\left[2(x+y)+1)\right] \ge  \sqrt x + \sqrt y$$

which is true indeed since, by AM-GM or rearrangement, $\sqrt{\frac xy}+\sqrt{\frac yx}\ge 2$ we have

$$\frac14\left(\sqrt{\frac xy}+\sqrt{\frac yx}\right)\left(2(x+y)+1)\right) \ge  x+y+\frac12\ge \sqrt x + \sqrt y $$

and the latter is true since

$$x+\frac14\ge 2\sqrt{\frac x 4}=\sqrt x$$